# ADFS server, allow x-domain

Tags: html, botframework, adfs, microsoft-teams

We have one scenario, using MS teams Task Module to popup and load a web page.

The web page is integrated with SSO(ADFS). When we load a web page in the popup, it will redirect to SSO link. Now the challenge is the Task Module (popup) inside using iframes to load a page, we have enabled iframe access in our domain(web page) and failing to load SSO page, because there also needs to enable iframe access (CORS).

Does anyone know how to enable CORS in ADFS?

Comment: How will we whitelist domains in AD FS ? or how will we trust domains in ADFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS in only available for ADFS on [Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/customize-http-security-headers-ad-fs).

Note that iframes are also allowed.

This functionality (other than CORS) has been back ported to ADFS on Server 2016.

"The functionality to customize the HTTP security response headers (except CORS Headers) using cmdlets: Get-AdfsResponseHeaders and Set-AdfsResponseHeaders was backported to AD FS 2016. You can add the functionality to your AD FS 2016 by installing KB4493473 and KB4507459."

Comment: How can we allow multiple domains using X-Frame-Options ( Set-AdfsResponseHeaders -SetHeaderName "X-Frame-Options" -SetHeaderValue "allow-from https://www.example.com" )?

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use a proxy to do the CORS, maybe it is better solution than config more backend code. Like more web frontend project like to use proxy to do the CROS work with backend API.

Comment: The web site is loading in third party domain ( teams.microsoft.com/) as an iframe.